# How do I define a sql query that either intersects a table selection or does not do the intersection at all?

Tags: database, postgresql

so regarding this question, I have 3 atomic queries from a database that I want to compose optionally based on a set of given parameters to create a query for a pet caretaker service. (This is for a project on database hence it is preferential to perform operations in SQL where possible.)

This is the schema I want CanBid(UserID, name, contact_number, price).

This is to serve as a complex search query in the database for parameters:
Start Date, end date, petCatagory, CareTaker Name

So I want on the front end fields to enter these parameters, and on the backend to perform these queries directly from the database. Thus my idea is to perform atomic queries on date range, petCategory, CareTaker Name as below, and perform set intersections in order to allow flexible searching by the user.

Pet Categories: eg "Dogs", "Cats" ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id as userid,
u.name as name,
u.contact_number as contact,
c.daily_price as price
FROM isAvailableOn a INNER JOIN Users u ON a.care_taker_user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN CanTakeCare c ON a.care_taker_user_id = c.care_taker_user_id
WHERE c.category_name LIKE '$1%';
```

Date Ranges: start date, end date eg '2022-01-01'

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id as userid,
u.name as name,
u.contact_number as contact,
c.daily_price as price
FROM isAvailableOn a
INNER JOIN Users u ON a.care_taker_user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN CanTakeCare c ON a.care_taker_user_id = c.care_taker_user_id
WHERE (a.available_date > DATE($1) AND a.available_date <= DATE($2))
```

Caretaker Name: eg "John" or "Jack"

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id as userid,
u.name as name,
u.contact_number as contact,
c.daily_price as price
FROM isAvailableOn a 
INNER JOIN Users u ON a.care_taker_user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN CanTakeCare c ON a.care_taker_user_id = c.care_taker_user_id
WHERE u.name LIKE '$1%'"
```

Since all these 3 queries have the same schema, I would like to ask you all for a way to compose the intersections of these 3 queries as a filtering mechanism, so that I can use the same endpoint on the server to handle all these queries at once. If possible i would like to perform all operations on the database in SQL operations, not via string parsing.

Hence on the server I would only do default argument parsing if inputs are invalid.
like if start_date is invalid the server will input a signal argument to SQL not to run the date filter query. lets say `not_valid`

Is it possible to do something like this? I am not very familiar with how plpgsql syntax works. Would like any advise on this!

```
FUNCTION ( customerName, startDate, endDate, pet_type
IF customerName != "not_valid":
    SELECT * FROM CustomerName(pet_type)
ENDIF
INTERSECT
IF pet_type != "not_valid":
    SELECT * FROM PetType(pet_type)
ENDIF
INTERSECT
IF startDate != "not_valid" AND endDate != "not_valid":
    SELECT * FROM DateRange(DATE(startDate), DATE(endDate))
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your middle tier, pass `NULL` for invalid values to your query.  Then use `COALESCE()` to turn those `NULL` values into conditions that will always return `true`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id as userid,
       u.name as name,
       u.contact_number as contact,
       c.daily_price as price
  FROM isAvailableOn a 
       JOIN Users u 
         ON a.care_taker_user_id = u.user_id
       JOIN CanTakeCare c 
         ON a.care_taker_user_id = c.care_taker_user_id
 WHERE c.category_name LIKE COALESCE($1, '')||'%'
   AND a.available_date > COALESCE($2, '1970-01-01')
   AND a.available_date <= COALESCE($3, '9999-12-31')
   AND u.name LIKE COALESCE($4, '')||'%';
```